# GreenShot - How to assign a hotkey to the "open image from clipboard"

Tags: greenshot

In this new computer I'm not able to set a hotkey to "open image from clipboard" via Greenshot.ini file.

This is the line I found but everytime I add a keyboard shortcut, the software doesn't recognize it:

**; Hotkey for opening the clipboard contents into the editor
ClipboardHotkey=Ctrl + Shift + Z**

Anyone had had this issue resolved ?

Comment: Greenshot has no such hotkey. You might be referring in *Preferences > Destination* to the options of specifying an image editor?

Comment: it has @harrymc , I have used it before... if you check the INI file there is a row for it... but for some reason my system, Greenshot version is not recognizing it. IT will even show in the pop-up menu when you right-click on the taskbar icon

Comment: @John , which one is that one? doesn't ring a bell. Thanks !

Comment: @John Found the solution, see my answer.

Comment: @harrymc The new feature doesn't have a *Preferences* -> *Hotkeys* entry yet, since it's still a development version.  With careful editing of *Greenshot.ini* (see my answer) we can start using it now !  (I'm so happy, been waiting for this feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version are you using?  The feature doesn't seem to exist in the latest stable version (1.2.10 Build 6) **but exists with a later unstable (development) version** such as [version 1.3.274](https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot/releases/tag/v1.3.274).  Maybe because it is an unofficial release we need to add the settings manually:

1. Install it and run it one time (Greenshot.ini will be created)
2. **Important**: Exit the program (so you can edit Greenshot.ini)
3. Add the following lines in `%AppData%\Greenshot\Greenshot.ini` (per instruction in the [new feature #1110 description](https://greenshot.atlassian.net/browse/FEATURE-1110))

   ```
   ; Hotkey for opening the clipboard contents into the editor
   ClipboardHotkey=Ctrl + Shift + Z
   ```
4. Start the program.  You should now see the option registered in the menu:
   [image: Greenshot menu]

I think what happened in your case is that you reinstalled an earlier version using Greenshot.ini from a later version.

Comment: Paul, mine has it:
https://imgur.com/dfeJIFL

Comment: I have version 1.2.10 Build 6

Comment: it never showed the option via preference --> General --> hotkey... only access was via INI file BUT once done it will show the shortcut in the pop-up window once you right-click the taskbar icon

Comment: @Orlando Interesting.  I'm trying out the unstable version 1.3.274.  Will update this answer with my findings.

Comment: @Orlando I have updated the findings from my experiment and added steps for other people who want to use this feature before official release.

Comment: you might think that every fresh install should overwrite any files as many installers will prompt (which greenshot did)... but well... the wonders of computers/softwares...

Comment: @Orlando Well, it's a development version, so I don't complain too much.  I'm actually happy to discover that function, thanks to your question!  If you're happy with my answer you can accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with the latest version... not sure what happened since I had installed this one before... The only different thing I did was I went to [www.filehippo.com](http://www.filehippo.com) and downloaded 2 much older version and try it out my modifying the INI file... no avail... then went back and downloaded the latest again and noticed it  had kept me previous ini edit row:

There you go!!! now I can assign a shortcut to my logitech mouse and Voila!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o7Fl.png)